# How to change the resolution of Android on a Pandaboard?

Tags: android, android-source, omap, pandaboard

I'm building Android 4.2.1 from AOSP targetting a Pandaboard ES, and I have to change the physical display resolution from 1920x1080 to 800x600 on the HDMI output.

I tried to append `omapfb.mode=hdmi:800x600@60`, `omapfb.mode=800x600@60`, or `video=omapfb:mode:800x600@60` to the `CONFIG_CMDLINE` of the .config generated by `make panda_defconfig` from OMAP kernel sources, but at each time adb doesn't seem to recognize the device anymore, and it disappears from "lsusb" command right after the boot.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to look for ro.sf.lcd_density in /system/build.prop

```
adb pull /system/build.prop
adb push build.prop /sdcard
```

then replace it carefully with root access on the board

See [LCD density explained](http://www.androidtablets.net/forum/android-tablet-usage-tips-tricks/9444-lcd-density-explained.html) to chose the appropriate value.

Comment: The problem is I need to change the physical resolution of the hdmi display (from 1920*1080), and I can't just scale the dip with a 2.4 factor (otherwise I'll end up with 800*450 instead of 800*600). Moreover, of what I've read, the dip property affects the aspect of what is rendered and not the physical resolution, and I really need to change the physical resolution because of a feature activated only at 800x600 resolution in my custom kernel.